# How to create permeant "cache" directory for AWS Lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a python script, dockerized and running as a Lambda function in AWS that performs data extraction on an XBRL file with py-xbrl when triggered. Pared down, the important part of the python script is:

```py
from xbrl.cache import HttpCache
from xbrl.instance import XbrlParser

def handler(event, context):
    sample_schema_url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/0000320193/000032019321000105/aapl-20210925.htm"

    cache = HttpCache('./cache')
    parser = XbrlParser(cache)

    xbrl_instance = XbrlParser.parse(sample_schema_url)
    return
```

Having a local cache of taxonomy links greatly speeds up the read time of other XBRL schemas with similar taxonomies - from 10s of seconds to 10ths of a second in most cases. But the cache must be specified as a file.

Currently, while this works, the cache is created and destroyed each time the Lambda function terminates. I think it remains while its in a warm state, but the triggers could be quite far apart.

What is the best way to import the cache from somewhere durable (S3 perhaps?) when the lambda function starts up, and export the cache back to that durable location when it closes down? I dont believe I can set an S3 bucket to be a filepath target directly.

Comment: Yes, S3 or EFS are usual choices.

Comment: Would you be able to give an example on how I would achieve that? I am still very new to AWS. I assume using Boto3 to copy in from the storage location, and save back out again. But would it involve another function for the import so it only runs once? What about the export back out?

Comment: You can mount an EFS volume that the Lambda function will see as a local file system folder, and copy the file there. However you need to be aware that EFS can be quite slow. It's a networked file system, not a local disk.

Comment: What is the lifetime of the data (i.e. how often do you have to refresh)?   Do you need to update it with every run of the Lambda?  If so, what does it mean to run "N" Lambdas at the same time - which Lambda has the "correct" data?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the sample code that implement a S3 cache backend

```py
import pickle
import base64
from s3pathlib import S3Path
from xbrl.instance import XbrlParser


def b64encode_url(url):
    return base64.b64encode(url.encode("utf-8")).decode("utf-8")


def get_data(url):
    return XbrlParser.parse(sample_schema_url)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    sample_schema_url = event["schema_url"]
    cache_key = b64encode_url(sample_schema_url)
    s3path_cache = S3Path("my-bucket", cache_key)
    if s3path_cache.exists():
        parse_result = pickle.loads(s3path_cache.read_bytes())
    else:
        parse_result = get_data(sample_schema_url)
        s3path_cache.write_bytes(pickle.dumps(parse_result))

    # keep doing what ever you want with parse result ...
```